# Selecting multiple columns from multiple rows in one column (subquery?)

Tags: mysql, select, mysql-5, mysql-5.1, group-concatenation

I'm working with MySQL 5.1.68.

I have a situation where I'd like to select rows from another table into a column.

[image]

I'd like to output this:

---

id # name # citizen_name (multiple citizen names)

1 # The Hague # Barack Obama, Marc Zuckerberg, George Bush

---

I know how to do this with multiple queries, but I'd like to do this with just one query. I've been looking at group_concat and concat_ws, but unfortunatly this hasn't brough me the result I was looking for. I've also tried to put the results from a SELECT sub query into a variable and CONCAT those results, but that didin't work either.

My SQL fiddle to show the schema and some test data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7c7e/1.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [**GROUP_CONCAT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to aggregate the citizen names first. Then use [**CONCAT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

```
SELECT CONCAT(id,' # ',name,' # ',citizens) listing FROM
(
    SELECT A.id,A.name,GROUP_CONCAT(B.name,' ',B.surname) citizens
    FROM city A INNER JOIN citizen B
    ON A.id = B.city_id GROUP BY A.id,A.name
) AA;
```

Here is the SQL Fiddle to prove it : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f4b3/1

If the names become too long due to truncation, you will have to extend [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len)'s maximum length. To set it to 16K, run the following:

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 1024 * 16;
SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len = 1024 * 16;
```

First line is for the session, the second is for all new DB Connections.

Comment: Please post your request as a separate question

Comment: My bad, didin't want to ask that after al..